# Will traffic from 'unrelated' searches improve my SEO?

Tags: seo, search-engine

I am a founder for a tech summer camp program. My website has a page full of resources for web-development meant for camp participants and has been getting lots of traffic from people querying html colors, css cheat sheet, and other similar terms.

My question is: will traffic from these terms hurt my SEO for queries involving things like summer camps,tech camps halifax, or other more related queries? or Is any traffic good for my SEO?

Note: We have no problem with people accessing these resources, so I haven't bothered to password protect it or add robots.txt or anything. The site is compcamp.ca and the resource page I mentioned is compcamp.ca/web-development-design-resources/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google ranks the site `compcamp.ca/web-development-design-resources/` well for search-queries like css cheat-sheet, because the content of your site contains the keywords and so on.
There are no Keywords for "tech camps halifax" and so on. So Google won't rank this subsite.

If you want to rank fpr "tech camps halifax" you have to take content on a site (i would expect the start page) which contains those keywords.

The other way round: Successful search queries on your cheat-sheet sub-site won't hurt your rankings from other sub-pages which delivers different information = different keywords.

I hope this is answering your question, don't bother to ask if not.